# TypeScript library + RxJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs5, typescript2.0

Look at this: https://github.com/asfernandes/rx-computed/tree/v0.0.2-alpha.5 in files https://github.com/asfernandes/rx-computed/blob/v0.0.2-alpha.5/lib/rx-computed.ts and https://github.com/asfernandes/rx-computed/blob/v0.0.2-alpha.5/test/rx-computed.ts

VSCode says there is no error, npm test runs ok, but when I use the library in another project, there is a problem of the RxJS skip method not defined.

The library compiles because the RxJS import in the test file is used in the lib file. How can I avoid this, as there is no sense to have it compiling with the test and not working outside.

Comment: Maybe create pull request?

Comment: Create pull request for what? I develop this library myself, and I do want a good compile environment that produces usable binaries, and want TypeScript support for that. Maybe it's a missing feature I didn't know.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.